# Scaling the input vs scaling the impulse response for an LTI system

Tags: fourier-transform, convolution, linear-systems

Two different cases:

1. We pass $x(t)$ to an LTI system with impulse response $h(2t)$ and get the output $y(t)$.
2. We pass $x(2t)$ to an LTI system with impulse response $h(t)$ and get the output $z(t)$.

I'm looking for possible restrictions (e.g. on the input / impulse response) such that the $y(t)$ and $z(t)$ are equal, if possible.

So far I have this:

$$
y(t) = x(t) * h(2t) \implies Y(j\omega) = X(j\omega) \frac{1}{2} H(j\omega/2)
$$

$$
z(t) = x(2t) * h(t) \implies Z(j\omega) = \frac{1}{2} X(j\omega/2)H(j\omega) 
$$

If we take, for example, $X(j\omega)$ from the first equation and plug into the other one, we get

$$
Z(j\omega) = \frac{Y(j\omega/2)H(j\omega)}{H(j\omega/4)}
$$

I'm stuck at this point to comment on the relation between $y(t)$ and $z(t)$ and assert some restrictions to make them equal possibly.

Comment: $w$ is not the same as $\omega$.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson "nit" is nit the same as "not" :-).   Dilip Nitpicker

Comment: :-)..... ........

Answer (score 2):

Aside from

1. Input that is only a constant value or
2. a System that does nothing to the signal, i.e. $H = \text{const.}$,

these things are *not* the same.

Sketch of a proof:

- Scaling input shifts energy to frequency components that hadn't energy before,
- Scaling the system means changes the Transfer Function, but keeps the system LTI, which means it can't add energy to any components that had none before.

Comment: I don't understand: if the input is constant, then outputs are not the same but time-scaled versions of each other, right? Also, if a system is doing nothing, it means its impulse response must be unit impulse, right (and not any other impulse)? In this case, still outputs are not the same but time scaled versions of each other?

Comment: As for the sketch of a proof: how come scaling with some number greater than 1 results in giving energy to the frequencies that didn't have any energy before; doesn't frequency response get shrunk, and not expanded?

Comment: I'm confused by your comments: let me address them individually:

Comment: *if the input is constant, then outputs are not the same but time-scaled versions of each other, right?* **wrong**, if the input is a constant, time-scaling doesn't change it.

Comment: *if a system is doing nothing, it means its impulse response must be unit impulse, right (and not any other impulse)?* **right**

Comment: *In this case, still outputs are not the same but time scaled versions of each other?* **wrong**, if you time-scale the unit impulse, it stays the unit impulse, and hence the output remains the same (i.e. identical to the input)

Comment: Re: your last comment: inputs in the question for the two cases are different, am i missing something? (one is $x(t)$, other is $x(2t)$).

Comment: *how come scaling with some number greater than 1 results in giving energy to the frequencies that didn't have any energy before; doesn't frequency response get shrunk, and not expanded?* Say your signal consists of a single oscillation of frequency $\omega_0$. Then, scaling that signal means that you get a new oscillation of frequency $2\omega$. There was no energy there before.

Comment: Re: your first comment: again, impulse responses differ: $h(t)$  vs $h(2t)$

Comment: You're getting tangled up in your own notation. Please write this down cleanly. You simply can't prove what you want to prove because it's wrong.

Comment: Okay, I understand the first part of the sketch of the proof thanks. My last question is: what do you mean by an LTI system can't add energy to components that didn't have before? (and how are we sure, there *are* frequency components that did not have any energy before, band-limitedness is assumed?

Comment: I mean it exactly as I wrote it: If there was no energy at some frequency $f_0$ in a signal before it went through an LTI system, then there's also no energy at that frequency after the signal went through the system. That's literally what the L in LTI implies!

Comment: No, i don't think there is a notational issue. I'm trying to say if input is constant i.e. $x(t) = x(2t) = c$, then **since the impulse responses in two cases in the question are different**, outputs will be different too. Similar goes for when impulse response is a unit impulse but inputs are arbitrary $x(t)$ and $x(2t)$, and that results in outputs that are the same as inputs i.e. $x(t)$ and $x(2t)$ since system is identity; hence the outputs are not the same but time-scaled versions of each other..

Comment: they are the same. it's really a matter of writing down the PSD of your output signal in both cases. This is really stuff you can do yourself with pen and paper!

Comment: Pencil-and-paper gives me this for the constant input case: $x(t) = 5$, $y(t) = x(t) * h(2t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 5 h(2\tau) d\tau$ and  $z(t) = x(2t) * h(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 5 h(\tau) d\tau$; and these two integrals do not evaluate to the same output in general..

Comment: ... if $x(t)=5$, then $X(f) = 5\delta(f)$, then $$X(f)H(f)= \begin{cases}0&f\ne0\\5\delta(0)H(0)&f=0\end{cases}.$$ That means no matter how your $h$, you always get the same value.

Comment: How come?? Doesn't $H(0)$ depend on $h$: $H(0) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(t)dt$?

Comment: whether you integrate $h(t)$ or $h(2t)$ from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ doesn't make any difference...

Comment: Really? But for example when $h(t) = 3^{-t}u(t)$ (where $u(t)$ is unit step), the integral gives 0.910 ($ = 1/\ln 3$) and for $h(2t) = 9^{-t}u(t)$, it gives 0.455 ($ = 1/\ln 9$)?

Comment: yes, really. Look at the formula: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(t)dt=\int_{-\infty/2}^{\infty/2} h(2t)dt=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(2t)dt$.

Comment: You forgot the multiplier 2 i.e. $2dt$ when changing variable.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for the responses.

Comment: Hi Marcus Müller ~10 months later: do you accept your mistake above, forgetting the 2 factor? I waited enough for the response I think

Comment: no, there's no mistake. Nothing to accept. $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(2t)\,\mathrm dt= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(t)\,\mathrm dt$; that's really just the definition of what it means to integrate with infinite bounds.

Comment: Yes, there is. When changing variable. https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/74108/scaling-the-input-vs-scaling-the-impulse-response-for-an-lti-system/74110?noredirect=1#comment156918_74110

Comment: Isn't there a 3rd party option on this website to figure out whats right here?

Comment: you're wrong. End of discussion, sorry.

Comment: I literally gave an example here https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/74108/scaling-the-input-vs-scaling-the-impulse-response-for-an-lti-system/74110?noredirect=1#comment156915_74110......

Comment: What's your objection to that, please?

Comment: your unit step example doesn't work for me, it seems incorrect. https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/74108/scaling-the-input-vs-scaling-the-impulse-response-for-an-lti-system/74110?noredirect=1#comment156918_74110 is a conclusive proof of that.

Comment: "doesn't work for me" What do you mean? WolframAlpha says it works: [first one](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+3%5E-x+UnitStep%28x%29+from+-inf+to+%2Binf) and the [second one](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+9%5E-x+UnitStep%282x%29+from+-inf+to+%2Binf).

Comment: There was a notification but I couldn't look the message but now it's gone. What was it?

Comment: At least you learned something :)